# Raspberry Pi B+ can't install node-red

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, raspbian-wheezy, apt, nodered

I read an article on the newest MagPi about node-red and I decided to install it. I used:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nodered
```

The 4th command produces:

```
E: Unable to locate package nodered
```

Does anyone know how to install nodered? I am using a Raspberry Pi B+.

Comment: What version of raspbian are you using?

Comment: I am not sure. How do you find out?

Comment: Run this and look at the Version variable cat /etc/*-release

Comment: I got that I am running Raspbian Wheezy.

Answer (score 3):

The website for this notes on the [installation page](http://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi.html) specifically for the Raspberry Pi that the project was included in the "Jessie" release distribution around November 2015. Did your `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` complete correctly - you might want to reboot after that and do another `sudo apt-get update` to be absolutely sure everything was updated from the "Wheezy" dist to the "Jessie" one - given that this will also change the first process from being the sysV `init` of the former to the `systemd` (default) of the latter a reboot is, I think, really a good idea.

My (RPi B+) went straight into the expected with a recent NOOBs + Raspbian:

```
pi@ulhura ~ $ sudo apt-get install nodered
[sudo] password for pi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-ares2 libv8-3.14.5 nodejs nodejs-legacy
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-ares2 libv8-3.14.5 nodejs nodejs-legacy nodered
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,251 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,567 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

And the expected output from the release information:

```
pi@ulhura ~ $ more /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

If you have nothing of your own construction on the Pi it may be worth replacing the distribution with a fresh install - if you want to avoid having to perform a dist-update that has not so far seems to have happened - but try a reboot first.

Comment: When I ran sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, my Pi said there were no upgrades.

Comment: Did anything happen the first time you ran that - it would only produce significant output once IMHO (when it DID the dist-update from Wheezy to Jessis) - but I am surprised that the release information file `/etc/os-release` did not also change - it is contained in the `base-files` package which should have changed version (from a `7+rpi` I think to the current, at time of writing `8+rpi`) in that dist-update - what does `sudo dpkg-query -W base-files` report currently?

Comment: It produces `base-files     7.1wheezy8+rpi1`

Comment: Yes, THAT version dates to May 2015 and is Wheezy (Raspbian 7) - but it is not clear why a dist-upgrade doesn't do what it implies it should do.

Comment: It might be because I use `adafruit-raspberrypi-bootloader` instead of `raspberrypi-bootloader`. I use a PiTFT with my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing via npm:

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_archive_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i node_archive_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-rpi.gpio
```

then:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm  node-red
```

Further details can be found [here](http://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi.html). Note that the linked page contains some info on potential issues with node-gyp.

Perhaps the better solution is to burn a new SD card with Raspbian Jessie, which already includes nodered.

Comment: I do not want to burn a new SD card as I am wanting to install node-red on a "Pi Portable" that already has all the software configured.

Comment: You can try install from npm as mentioned above